# OnApplyTemplate not called in Custom Control

Tags: wpf

I have a Custom Control which uses some PART controls:

```
 [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_TitleTextBox", Type = typeof(TextBox))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_TitleIndexText", Type = typeof(Label))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_TimeCodeInText", Type = typeof(TextBlock))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_TimeCodeOutText", Type = typeof(TextBlock))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_ApprovedImage", Type = typeof(Image))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_CommentsImage", Type = typeof(Image))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_BookmarkedImage", Type = typeof(Image))]
    public class TitleBoxNew : Control
    {
        static TitleBoxNew()
        { 
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof(TitleBoxNew),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TitleBoxNew)));
        } 

        public TitleBoxNew() { }

        // ... rest of class
    }
```

This control is overriding OnApplyTemplate:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
      base.OnApplyTemplate();

      InitializeEvents();
}
```

Which works well, most of the time. I have added the control inside a custom tab control in a window and somehow OnApplyTemplate is never called for that control! Why doesn't this work as I expect?

Comment: you are a first time member and you are using the F word. Try to see if this community likes it before posting it.

Answer (score 49):

For anyone else who might stumble upon this post, I was having the same issue and I managed to solve it by adding the following into the AssemblyInfo.cs of the project containing my custom control:

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
    //(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
    // or application resource dictionaries)
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
    //(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
    // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
```

My control's template is located in the file Theme/Generic.xaml in the same project as the control.

Comment: This solved my problem after we moved some WPF custom controls to a regular C# Class Library which was initially not created as a "WPF Custom Control Library". BTW: Also added the required <ProjectTypeGuids> XML element to the .csproj to upgrade the class library to a "real" WPF class library.

Answer (score 34):

The other two answers are correct...but not complete. According to [this post](http://horth.com/winblog/?p=25) (and my experience of just resolving this issue) there are 4 things you need to check: (for some reason the code blocks in this post wouldn't stay formatted if I used numbers or dashes...so letters it is)

A. The controls template and styles should be located in the `Generic.xaml` file a folder called `Themes` of the root of your project.

B. Make sure your namespaces are correct in the `Generic.xaml`

C. Set the style key in the constructor of your control. It is also widely recommended you put the following in a static constructor.

```
 static YourControl()
 {
      DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(YourControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(YourControl)));
 }
```

D. Ensure the following is in your assemblyinfo.cs

```
 [assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, 
 //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
 //(used if a resource is not found in the     
 // or application resource dictionaries)
 ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly 
 //where the generic resource dictionary is located
 //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
 // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
 )]
```

Comment: Step `A` was enough to solve my problem thanks! (`uwp`)

Comment: My themes folder was not in the root of the project. That solved the issue.

Comment: It was A as well for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I can't see your constructor, but don't forget to set the DefaultStyleKey:

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TitleBoxNew), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TitleBoxNew)));
```

Comment: Yes i frogot to mention that, i already got this:

static TitleBoxNew()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TitleBoxNew), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TitleBoxNew)));
        }
        public TitleBoxNew()
        {
        }

Comment: Please edit your orignal post to contain your constructor; comments aren't the correct spot for code.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to add my own answer because both the above answers are incomplete as I have been struggling with this problem for some time now.

As said by MoMo and Kai G above:

> A. The controls template and styles should be located in the
>   Generic.xaml file a folder called Themes of the root of your project.
>
> B. Make sure your namespaces are correct in the Generic.xaml
>
> C. Set the style key in the constructor of your control.
>
> D. Ensure the theme attribute is in the assemblyinfo.cs file

BUT you also need to ensure that your Generic.xaml file is set for the Build Action as **Page:Do Not copy.**

If you fail to do this or the value was somehow set to something other than this, the `OnApplyTemplate()` method will not be invoked.

Comment: Part D is of special importance, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Answer of @MoMo is correct, but additionally:

E: It is expected that the Themes/Generic.xaml is in the root of your project. If this is not the case and your Generic.xaml is not in the root then you have to create a directory Themes with Generic.xaml in the root (Generic.xaml is just of type ResourceDictionary). In that Generic.xaml you need to reference to the location of your Generic.xaml.

e.g.:

`<ResourceDictionary Source="/Foo.Bar;component/Controls/FooControl/Themes/Generic.xaml" />`

Answer (score 0):

beside all mentioned above which is correct and you should check for,

actually OnApplayTemplete() is called but after all property changed calls and I don't know why, it should be called first thing

so if you are using your PARTs names to get element it will get errors because wpf will not find until OnApplayTemplete() called
so, you must add if (your part element != null) condition in front of any code depend on the PARTs names

then inside OnApplayTemplete() method it self recall all your logical method again and it will work fine

```
    TextBox textBox;
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
            {
                base.OnApplyTemplate();
                //onther way to get elements & PARTs
                textBox= Template.FindName("PART_TitleTextBox", this) as TextBox;

                MyMethod();
    
            }
    private void MyMethod()
    {
if (textBox == null) return;
//your logical code here
    }
```