# Is there any way to debug xaml to establish why OnApplyTemplate is not being called

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have a wpf custom control that I have been using as a means to teach myself various aspects of Custom Control development.

I have a seemingly recurring problem where after working as expected for a while the control will suddenly start throwing exceptions that can be traced back to the fact that for some reason OnApplyTemplate has stopped being called.

My solution to this (if indeed you can call it that ) has been to rebuild the control from scratch, verify that it once again calls OnApplyTemplate and carry on working.  However after more work on the control it will once again stop calling OnApplyTemplate.

I can see nothing in the actual code files that I've done or added that would cause this to happen, so I assume it must emanate from the xaml, but as there appears to be no straightforward way to debug that I'm at a loss as to how to correct this.  I can't believe that control developers aare constantly rebuilding their controls from scratch so this must be my error, the question being where is it (and by definition how do I find the where) and then how might I go about correcting it.  For the time being I just need to establish the where.

I would really like to establish why this starts to happen, so that I can avoid doing whatever it is that I must be doing that leaves a working control one minute in a non working mode the next.

Comment: I noticed it once or twice, but can't remember what I did. I probably used BeginInit/EndInit instead, or loaded. This could be related to modifying the template of a control in xaml.

Comment: Just for the sake of order of elimination, could you go to your assemblyinfo.cs and make sure it has `ResourceDictionaryLocation.None` then `ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly` are in there? If not, throw them in there in that order (comma between).

Comment: Ah yea, should have looked, [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939787/onapplytemplate-not-called-in-custom-control)?

Comment: @ChrisW.  Yes those are both there (although the vb equivalent in my case).

Comment: @adminSoftDK  This is what I'm starting to suspect , ie the template has been altered, but the question becomes what bit of the alteration is causing the issue, hence the question.  I've looked at loads of SO q & A's on this.  All of the basic suggestions I've checked and followed.  Issues with Xaml now seem the most likely, but how do we debug those?